# how to create foreach loop in powershell with equal to command

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

Im starting to learn PowerShell and have been trying to create a foreach loop so that if one of the JSON items has a status other than STARTED, it runs a command using its name as a variable in the executable command. Here is what my json txt file looks like;

```
{
  "UNIT": {
    "name": "AB",
    "address": "fadasdaer",
    "status": "MIA"
  },
  "UNIT": {
    "name": "CD",
    "address": "fadasdahsfaaer",
    "status": "STARTED"
  },
    "UNIT": {
    "name": "EF",
    "address": "9afahegt",
    "status": "DEAD"
  }
}
```

And what I am trying to do is read this from my `json.txt` and get it to run a foreach loop and execute a command where the name is incorporated in the command. I currently have something like this, but my PowerShell understand is limited and it doesnt work...

```
$JSON = json.txt
$check = $JSON | ConvertFrom-Json
$started=STARTED

foreach($unit in $check.unit){
    if ($unit.status -notmatch $started) {
    $name=$unit.name
    executable.exe start $name
    }

}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$started=STARTED` -> `$started = 'STARTED'`

Comment: Your JSON is malformed.  You can't have duplicate keys.

Answer (score 7):

Your primary problem is that your JSON is malformed: it defines a *single object* and then defines its `UNIT` property *multiple times*.

You should define it as an *array*: note the enclosing top-level `[...]` and the absence of `UNIT` properties:

```
[
  {
    "name": "AB",
    "address": "fadasdaer",
    "status": "MIA"
  },
  {
    "name": "CD",
    "address": "fadasdahsfaaer",
    "status": "STARTED"
  },
  {
    "name": "EF",
    "address": "9afahegt",
    "status": "DEAD"
  }
]
```

With both the JSON input and your other syntax problems corrected:

```
$JSON = 'json.txt'
$check = Get-Content -Raw $JSON | ConvertFrom-Json
$started = 'STARTED'

foreach ($unit in $check) {
  if ($unit.status -notmatch $started) {
    $name = $unit.name
    executable.exe start $name
  } 
}
```

---

If you cannot fix the JSON at the source, you can *transform it yourself* before passing it to `ConvertFrom-Json`:

```
$check = (Get-Content -Raw $JSON) `
  -replace '\A\{', '[' `
  -replace '\}\Z', ']' `
  -replace '"UNIT": ' | ConvertFrom-JSON
```

Comment: unfortunately, my json is always giving me the UNIT at the start... it can never be changed... is there are a way to integrate through each row of the JSON file? Possibly change each key in the file?